# How to delete a Person Account in Apex Test

Tags: apex, unit-test, apextestrunresult

I have difficulty to delete Person Account(PA) in Apex test. **The reason is that I cannot figure out how to disable the associated user record.**

The org has Salesforce SSO and PA feature enabled. Here is my code logic in Apex test:

Test function body:

```
    Account pa = insertOnePARecord();
    User u = insertOneUserRecord(pa); // relation: user.contactId = pa.PersonContactId

    user.IsPortalEnabled = false; // need to disable the user before deleting PA;
    update user;
    Test.startTest();

    // DML for PA needs to be in a future method
    // Details: https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000008wAZIAY
    deletePA();
    Test.stopTest();
```

//

```
@future
private static void deletePA() {
    system.debug('future--' + user);
    Account pa = [
        SELECT Id, PersonContactId
        FROM Account
        WHERE FirstName = 'John0'
        LIMIT 1
    ];
    delete pa;
}
```

Error of running the test

`Your attempt to delete John0 Doe0 could not be completed because it is associated with the following portal users.: 00d1x0000008ajnuaa20200103162722458811@test00d1x0000008ajnuaa.org`

**interesting point 1** -- in the dev console of the org, if I set a user.isPortalUserEnabled to false, then delete the corresponding PA record, there is no error.

**interesting point 2** -- system.debug() in the future method shows that the `user.isPortalUserEnabled` value is back to `true`. How come?

Comment: Maybe because you are referencing the contact in the user record. What happens if you don't do that? Do you need a portal user in your test?

Comment: In the org business logic, all PAs are associated with users. I need to use Apex to delete any given PA record. In addition, it's mysterious why in the future method, the user comes back to live..

Comment: @RenatoOliveira you are right, if I don't link it to a portal user, test goes well. But this doesn't solve my problem as mentioned in the above comment.

Comment: I'm not sure - and won't post this as an answer right now - but I think you should deactivate the user too (set the `IsActive` field as `false`). If that doesn't work either, try removing the contact's id from the user record before deleting the contact.